# InDesign: how to only select objects on page, but not on pasteboard?

Tags: adobe-indesign, selections

In Illustrator there is the "Select all on Artboard" option. I was wondering if there is a similar option in InDesign that I can't find that does the same thing – i.e. selects everything on the page/pages but not objects on the pasteboard, because this isn't a default option (at least not in CS6, I don't know about CC).

Maybe a script that can be turned into a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: No pre-packaged command for this. So yeah, scripting maybe.